# EventArgs.Empty is a field that goes in circles. How can this be possible?

Tags: c#

If you look at the value of EventArgs.Empty by inserting a break point in VisualStudio, it seems that it goes in circles.

```
EventArgs.Empty                 {System.EventArgs}
    ◢static member
        ◢Empty                  {System.EventArgs}
            ◢static member 
                ◢Empty          {System.EventArgs}
                    ◢...
```

How can this be possible? And how can you implement such a 'EventArgs.Empty' like field? I've already tried to recreate a field like this, by looking at the exact definition of EventArgs, but all I get is a null point exception.

Comment: Look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/eventargs.cs,9a1496aa60befd10) if you want to see how to do it.  The behavior is the behavior you see any time an object has a member that is its own type.

Comment: Just static field of the same type. `class MyEventArgs { public static readonly MyEventArgs Empty = new MyEventArgs(); }`

Comment: To understand recursion you have to understand recursion

Comment: @RayKoopa -- nice!

Comment: @RayKoopa This isn't recursion though.

Comment: @Sevy Yes it is, it shows the static members of EventArgs, which in turn contain a static member of type EventArgs which shows the static members of EventArgs, which in turn contain a static member of type EventArgs which shows the static members of EventArgs, which in turn contain a static member of type EventArgs which shows the static members of EventArgs, which in turn contain a static member of type EventArgs which shows the static members of EventArgs..

Comment: @RayKoopa Not all infinite sequences are recursive in nature.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but this is an infinite sequence caused by recursion.

Comment: @RayKoopa But it's not.  An event args instance does not contain a static member; static members belong to the type, not to the instance.  The empty event args *doesn't* contain another empty event args.  If it was an *instance* field then it would actually be recursive.

Comment: @Servy -- From https://www.google.com/search?q=recursive&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8: "relating to or involving a program or routine of which a part requires the application of the whole, so that its explicit interpretation requires in general many successive executions."  "a part" is the `Empty` member, and the whole is `EventArgs` itself.  "many" in this case is infinite.

Comment: @Servy I know that, it's about the output sequence, not the logical "assembly hierarchy" / class design.

Comment: @rory.ap This fails to meet the specific statement of "so that its explicit interpretation requires in general many successive executions". There is only ever zero or one executions, not arbitrarily many.

Comment: @RayKoopa If you look *purely* at the results you merely have an infinite sequence, not necessarily a recursively defined infinite sequence.

Comment: @Servy -- I'm interpreting "recursion" as it applies to this case more abstractly.  "Executions" by my interpretation are the act of drilling down through `EventArgs.Empty.Empty.Empty...` in the locals window.  Not everything needs to be taken so literally.

Comment: This is not a recursion. static variable is a member of the type, not of the instance. The circle you see is typical to a singleton but is not a recursion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is probably implemented something like this:

```
class EventArgs
{
     public static readonly EventArgs Empty;

     static EventArgs(){
         Empty = new EventArgs();
     }
}
```

Comment: If you want to improve your answer edit your answer, don't post a second answer.

Comment: Oops, I made another answer instead of an edit. I deleted the other one.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. If I look in the System.EventArgs file the actual definition of the EventArgs' construction is not there. Maybe it's partly denfined elsewhere with the definition what like you said. But I wonder. Is using this kind of (not recursive) self circling class recommended?

Comment: It is a common construct. Every object has `this`, which also points to itself.

Comment: Oh, why didn't I thought of that. I feel so dumb. Thank you so much. It's been so helpful.